# Cannot connect to Coral Dev Board (Edge TPU)

Tags: tpu, google-coral

While following the instructions on [Get Started with Edge TPU Dev Board](https://coral.withgoogle.com/tutorials/devboard/), I can't get past Step 2:

```
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

The issue is that screen immediately returns

```
[screen is terminating]
```

I have verified the contents of /etc/udev/rules.d/65-edgetpu-board.rules, verified the dmesg output, tried different USB ports, verified that all screen instances are closed, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Solution = run screen command with sudo:

```
$ sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Comment: Glad you already figured this one out, but I did ran into similar issue before. from the official "Get started" instruction, most of them are missing `sudo` make sure you add `sudo` for others as well.

Comment: The reason you need sudo is because of the permissions on `/dev/ttyUSB0`. It is typically owned by `root:dialout`, so if you add yourself to the `dialout` group, you won't need `sudo`. You can do this once via `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $(whoami)`. You'll need to log out and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

First you should flash your `iptables`

**Coammands:**

```
sudo iptables -F 
mdt devices
```